# No COM port is being assigned to my USBasp AVR programmer

Tags: arduino, usb, avr, libusb, usb-drive

I'm trying to program a ATMMEGA32 using a USBasp programmer. when i plug in the programmer, it appears among 'USB devices' in device managment but it does not exist in Ports tab. 
how can i assign a COM port to my programmer ?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [imgurl.ir](http://imgurl.ir/uploads/v2801_.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

i have found out my solution !
it doesn't matter if a COM port is assigning to your programmer !
i just flashed my code on micro using progisp :)